# how can I run multiple go programs exist in different directory at a time?

Tags: ubuntu, go

I have different directories such as `DBconnection` , `APIRequest` , `APIResponse` etc.

All codes are interconnected. How can I run these at a time. 
The **go run** *.go* needed to be exist all files in a directory.

But I have multiple directories.

Any kind of help or suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: `go build` if I right understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly: you could write a little shell script executing them one after the other:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

go run /ParentPath/DBconnection/execfile.go
go run /ParentPath/APIRequest/execfile.go
go run /ParentPath/APIResponse/execfile.go
```

You could also create a go program executing the different packages in go routines, then you do not need to start multiple go programs.